# How to print a list of objects with properties?

Tags: c#, list, object

I'm a beginner of C#, I have this class:

```
public Dipendente(String Id, String Nome, String Cognome, Contratto TipoContratto, DateTime Data_assunzione, double Stipendio, Dipendente Tutor)
{
    this.Id = Id;
    this.Nome = Nome;
    this.Cognome = Cognome;
    this.TipoContratto = TipoContratto;
    this.DataAssunzione = Data_assunzione;
    this.StipendioMensile = Stipendio;
    this.Tutor = Tutor;
}

public static Dipendente GetDipendenteFromPersona(Persona persona, Contratto contratto, DateTime data_assunzione, double stipendio, Dipendente tutor)
{
    Dipendente result = null;
    result = new Dipendente(persona.Id, persona.Nome, persona.Cognome, contratto, data_assunzione, stipendio, tutor);
    return result;
}
```

In the main I have a list of objects like this:

```
Dipendente dip1 = Dipendente.GetDipendenteFromPersona(p1, lstContratti[1], new DateTime(2000, 10, 10), 1000, null);
List<Dipendente> lstDipendenti = new List<Dipendente> {dip1, dip2, dip3, dip4, dip5, dip6, dip7, dip8};
```

I need to print each item in the list with his property, which is the best way to do that?

I've tried with  this but obviously didn't get property values:

```
foreach (Dipendente dip in lstDipendenti)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(dip);
}
```

Comment: Can you show your desired output?

Comment: @Sweeper I would to print Id, nome, cognome, tipocontratto defined in Dipendente

Comment: Can't you just print `dip.Id`, `dip.Nome`, `dip.Cognome` etc?

Comment: @Sweeper I have to print them from the list

Comment: @marko `dip` _is_ an item in your list. It's the variable declared in the foreach loop, isn't it?

Comment: Just override `ToString` method in your class and provide implementation to it , then call it in that for each loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let each class (`Dipendente`) instance *speak for itself*, [.ToString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netframework-4.8) is the very place for this:

> Returns a string that represents the current object.
>
> ...It converts an object to its string representation so that it is suitable for display...

```
 public class Dipendente 
 {
     ...

     public override string ToString() 
     {  
         // Put here all the fields / properties you mant to see in the desired format
         // Here we have "Id = 123; Nome = John; Cognome = Smith" format
         return string.Join("; ",
           $"Id = {Id}",
           $"Nome = {Nome}", 
           $"Cognome = {Cognome}"  
         );
     }
 }
```

then you can put

```
 foreach (Dipendente dip in lstDipendenti)
 {
     // Or even System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(dip);
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(dip.ToString());
 }
```